# working with NSMutableArray data handeling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 classes:
**MainVC
DownloadedFilesView**

In MainVC class I have a NSMutableArray which stores list of all files of iPhone Directory. This array is datasource for my tableview (present in DownloadedFilesView). Upon selecting particular row (from MainVC tableview), I'm sending this data from MainVC to DownloadedFilesView like this:

```
if (indexPath.section == 1) {

    DownloadedFilesView *downloadView = [[DownloadedFilesView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DownloadedFilesView" bundle:nil];

    int count;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];

    for (count = 0; count < (int)[directoryContent count]; count++)
    {
        NSString *fileNames = [directoryContent objectAtIndex:count];
        [downloadView.arrayOfDirFiles addObject:fileNames];
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:downloadView animated:YES];
}
```

and I'm saving this datasource into another array "arrayOfDirFiles" (which is in DownloadedFilesView). Now I'm initializing this array in

```
initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

like:

```
arrayOfDirFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Now this array is datasource for my tableview in  DownloadedFilesView

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (theTableView.editing) {
        //arrayOfFileNamesToSave is the array which I want filtered when selecting particular cell
        [arrayOfFileNamesToSave addObject:[arrayOfDirFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    //NSLog(@"aaa....%@",arrayOfFileNamesToSave);
}
```

Now this is throwing an error. What is the best way to make this working? Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Can you add the error description?

Comment: Your post is muddy and unclear. What line is throwing an error? Is it a compiler error or a runtime error? Is the code that you posted from your MainVC object? What is the full method for both blocks of code?

Comment: I was actually calling it wrong way, just discovered. :) Thanks for reading my post and trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to pass the whole directoryContent array to downloadView.

```
downloadView.arrayOfDirFiles = directoryContent
```

Please ensure that arrayOfDirFiles is defined as strong/retain in DownloadedFilesView.

Comment: Thanks Pei. I found what was wrong in my code. :)